# Cannot find referenced source: packages

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have this pubspec.yaml

```dart
    name: Dart Pages
    description: The Dart platform.
    dependencies:
      web_components: any
      mongo_dart: any
```

then I run Tools > Pub Install, the operation completes successfully.

When I run the application I get the following error:

```dart
    dart --enable-checked-mode web\page.dart
    Unable to open file: C:/Users/Samer/Documents/GitHub/dart/web/packages/mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart'file:///C:/Users/Samer/Documents/GitHub/dart/web/page.dart': Error: line 1 pos 1: library handler failed
    #import("package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart");
```

I'm using Windows 7 64bit & Latest Dart Editor version 0.2.1_r14167

The issues seems not be with only mongo_dart, but all other libraries as well, the editor is looking for the wrong path over packages at /dart/web/packages, while i see a in folder /dart/packages.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Can you please post a description of your file layout? Can you confirm if the web directory got a symlink to packages directory? Can you paste in the code for page.dart? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `pub install` since you created the "web" directory? If not, try that. You need to have a "packages" directory inside the directory that contains your Dart entrypoint in order for "package:" imports to resolve correctly.

Pub will create those directories for you, but it needs to know to do that. If you add a new directory to your package, you'll want to run `pub install` again so it add a "packages" directory to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with TeamCity. On my development machine I can do `pub get` and `pub build` over and over and it works just great, but this only worked the very first time I built the solution using TeamCity.

After a lot of messing around I finally discovered, mostly by trial and error, that the problem was caused by TeamCity cleaning the folder before building the solution.

I can't find any reasonable documentation for how `pub` works, and I don't know why this only works the very first time, but my trial and error discovered that executing `pub cache repair` on every build before `pub get` and finally `pub build` works repeatably, and my TeamCity project now builds successfully every time.

Comment: That sounds cumbersome. I don't know TeamCity. Is it possible it runs several `pub get` concurrently? Maybe there is a way to specify the pub-cache directory to use to use a different one for each instance (have to look it up, not on my computer yet)

Comment: It is possible to configure TeamCity to start a new build even when the current build is still running, but this is _not_ the default setting. It is also possible to get TeamCity to always use the same folder for a particular build, and not clear the contents between builds; which solves this problem but it's not a clean build. I like to know that if I get my solution from source control that it will build into an empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar here, with the js-interop package. I changed the ':' to '/' and it worked.

Original declaration:

```
    import("package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart");
```

Modified declaration:

```
    #import("package/mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart");
```

You could also try this (It has worked to me):

```
    import 'packages/mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
```

Comment: This may work sometimes, coincidentally, but you really don't want to do this. Doing so will break transitive imports. If A imports B which imports C using the above syntax, it's unlikely to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add an additional library where you import mongo_dart.dart and then import the library in your main. It's a weird solution I know but it worked for me when I was trying to get Google Maps running inside Dart.

More here: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/ORXJmmmH3fA/WIKyBik1e7sJ

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems trying to import unittest. I'm running Eclipse 4.2 in windows 7 64 bit with the dart editor plugin.

Deleting the 'pub' folder under c:\USERS\<*user*>\AppData\Roaming\ worked for me.

The credit goes to Samer Ali on the darlang google group for this one, see [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/ORXJmmmH3fA/oyg5tVVxGigJ).