# Unable to find pub package references in DART app

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have followed the directions on [setting up web_components for DART](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/tools.html#editor-background-compilation). This code snippet from the page is giving me problems:

```
import 'package:web_components/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/app.html']);
}
```

When I try to run, this is the error I am receiving:

> dart --enable-checked-mode --package-root=C:\Users\John Jelinek\dart\
>   build.dart
>
> Unable to open file: C:\Users\John
>   Jelinek\dart\web_components/component_build.dart'file:///C:/Users/John
>   Jelinek/Documents/dart/webComponents/build.dart': Error: line 1 pos 1:
>   library handler failed import
>   'package:web_components/component_build.dart'; ^

I do not know why it is trying to find the reference in `C:\Users\John Jelinek\dart` when the project lives in `C:\Users\John Jelinek\Documents\dart`. By the way, I am on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. What is the best way to make sure my pub packages reference the appropriate location?

Note: I have found [someone else having similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161155/cannot-find-referenced-source-packages), but none of those answers worked for me.

Comment: It could be the spaces on the path. Try a path without spaces and see if the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these directions and see if they fix your issue:

http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-web-component-with-dart.html