# Pub does not download dependencies on Windows 7 after the update to lib v2 (SDK 0.3.1_r17328)

Tags: dart, dart-pub

After the update to the version 0.3.1_r17328 of Dart SDK and Dart Editor I have some trouble to import some library particulary Args library. I have the same problem both directly importing Args or importing Web_ui where Args is one of the dependencies.

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```dart
name:  notes
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
  web_ui: 0.3.0+1
```

or:

```dart
name:  notes
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
  args: 0.3.1+1
```

Here is the error generate from *build.dart*

```dart
Unable to open file:     C:/Users/Fabio/Dropbox/progetti/note/packages/args/args.dart'package:web_ui/component_build.dart': Error: line 25 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:args/args.dart';

'file:///C:/Users/Fabio/Dropbox/progetti/note/build.dart': Error: line 1 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems that the Cache folder (Pub) has been corrupted.

I have deleted the folder Cache: C:\Users\<*UserName*>\AppData\Roaming\Pub

Then i run `pub install` from command line and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I was getting the same error with my windows XP machine.

> In the end, I logged into my windows 7 machine and was able to
>   download the packages, zipped them up and pasted the libraries into my
>   windows XP dart editor.  Success!

I had no reason to believe I had the exact proxy issue @shindokaku had as I am using my home computer.

I tried all the suggestions on deleting the .cache files, pub.lock files and the packages folder and retrying.  I uninstalled dart editor and tried again.  I also tried using the git resources to download web-ui and running commands through the command line to no avail

Including suggestions in this similar questions:

- [cannot-find-referenced-source-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161155/cannot-find-referenced-source-packages)
- [is-there-a-workaround-for-pub-dependency-resolution-through-proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849336/is-there-a-workaround-for-pub-dependency-resolution-through-proxies)

Comment: After updating to Dart Editor/SDK version 0.3.7_r18717 I now get the following error that WinXP isn't supported.  "Pub install failed, [64] Sorry, but pub is not supported on Windows XP."  At least there is a nicer error message and I know I should finally buy a newer computer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been haunting me over and over for a few weeks. I am not using Windows, so this answer is not intended to help the original poster who is using Windows 7.

If you are using Linux here are the steps I use to repair corrupted pub cache.

Go to the top level directory of your app. You should see at least pubspec.lock, pubspec.yaml, a folder named packages, and a folder named web. 
Delete your pubspec.lock, and packages folder.

*[Make sure you aren't storing your own libraries in the packages folder]*

```
cd ~/dart/myApp/
rm -r packages
rm pubspec.lock
```

Now once you have removed these files:

```
pub cache repair
```

Note 1: if your dart-sdk is not in your systems $PATH, than you will want to use the absolute path to the sdk when using the above command. Comment if you need that explained.

Note 2: This is working solution with Dart 1.5.3. I have not tested this on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your pubspec.lock file and packages directory in the root folder of the project. Then run pub install again, when things get wacky thats what I do.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run `pub update`. I have sometimes found that this doesn't work as expected from the editor, but generally works quite smoothly when called from the command line.